# Hide vertical scrollbar with google maps

Tags: html, css, google-maps

I am using an embedded google maps with some css attached to it. However, I am using `overflow:hidden;` but the vertical scroll bar is still displayed.

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/5e3974e997041763a475a475a8dfd69d.png]

Is there a way to fix this? This is my code:

```
<style>
.map-responsive{
    overflow:hidden;

    padding-bottom:56.25%;
    position:relative;
    height:0;
}
.map-responsive iframe{
    left:0;
    top:0;

    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
}
</style>

<div class="hideoverflow">
<div class="map-responsive">
<iframe width="950" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=place_id:ChIJya9E14i2xUcRLWzbVXjmqMg&key=API_KEY-WMxApjPI&zoom=15" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
The problem is the outer container and padding/margin, below is a full working example: 


<html>
<body>
<head>
<style>
html , body { height: 100%; overflow:hidden; padding:0; margin:0 }  
</style>
</head>

<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d867278.573568972!2d34.331652102906006!3d31.884666128727865!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x151cf2d28866bdd9%3A0xee17a001d166f686!2sPalestine!5e0!3m2!1sen!2s!4v1504401844245" 
 scrolling="no" height="100%" width="100%" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you maybe know how to move the box with the route and save button to the top-middle of the map? https://gyazo.com/324dfebe47d6120b17bc1453205f2486 And is it possible to resize that box, maybe so that it gets smaller if the map gets smaller?

Comment: You are welcome! however, I cannot understand your second question, Could you please more clear with your requirement ?